# Notepad++ - How can I add a dot (.) to every alternate line?

Tags: notepad++

I have a sample data like this:

```
#10009
#10009
#10010
#10010
```

And I want to make it like:

```
#10009
#10009.
#10010
#10010.
```

Comment: The `#` was part of the original question. See the first edition source: http://superuser.com/revisions/a520e588-4a37-4ab9-9f9b-e03fcfc5ae31/view-source

Answer (score 6):

Find & Replace, "Regular expression":

Find `(.*\r\n.*)(\r\n)`, replace with  `\1.\2`

(Assumes you have Windows line endings and the last line ends in a `\r\n`)

---

Explanation:

- `.*` matches anything any number of times.
- `\r\n` is Windows carriage-return line-feed end of line.
- `(` and `)` denote capture groups. These are what the `\1` and `\2` refer to in the replace string.

Comment: Also, make sure the _. matches newline_ option box is not checked, or this will give undesired results.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use macro recording to solve this.  If you put your cursor before the first of the pairs (on line one), hit Start Recording, then hit "Down|End|.|Down|Home" and then Stop Recording.  Then you can use Macro|Run a macro multiple times|Run until end of file.

The Regex solutions offered can be more powerful, but using a macro to solve simple problems can be easier to understand and faster for those not well versed in Regex.